# How to loop a toggle classList infinitely through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get a cycle/loop effect on 3 H1 elements, displaying a purple font color for each H1 for some seconds and then change to another H1 right below the first one.

I wanted this effect to be infinite and I thought about using `for loop` and `setInterval` but I'm getting anywhere.

```
setInterval(changeColorLoop(), 2000);

function changeColorLoop() {
  const titleArtArray = document.querySelectorAll(".art-text");

  for (var i = 0; i < titleArtArray.length; i++) {
    titleArtArray[i].classList.toggle = ".purple";
  }
}



  <div class="art-column">
                <h1 class="art-text">Think</h1>
                <h1 class="art-text">Design</h1>
                <h1 class="art-text">Code</h1>
              </div>


.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets the "animation" going. Needs a little polishing. Edit: Polished, thanks to @jeanjacquesgourdin. Edit 2: Added some CSS transition

```js
let index = 0;

function changeColorLoop() {
  const titleArtArray = document.querySelectorAll(".art-text");

  titleArtArray[index % 3].classList.toggle("purple");
  titleArtArray[(index + 1) % 3].classList.toggle("purple");
  index++
}

setInterval(changeColorLoop, 1000);
```

```css
.art-text {
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="art-column">
  <h1 class="art-text purple">Think</h1>
  <h1 class="art-text">Design</h1>
  <h1 class="art-text">Code</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you can do something like

```
let index = 0;
const titleArtArray = document.querySelectorAll(".art-text");

setInterval(()=>{
  titleArtArray[index].classList.toggle = ".purple";
  titleArtArray[index+1].classList.toggle = ".purple";
  index = (index + 1) % 3
}, 2000);

  <div class="art-column">
    <h1 class="art-text purple">Think</h1>
    <h1 class="art-text">Design</h1>
    <h1 class="art-text">Code</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:

```
 <script>
  setInterval(() => {
    const titleArtArray = document.querySelectorAll(".art-text");
    titleArtArray[0].classList.add("purple");
    setTimeout(() => {
      titleArtArray[0].classList.remove("purple");
      titleArtArray[1].classList.add("purple");
      setTimeout(() => {
        titleArtArray[1].classList.remove("purple");
      titleArtArray[2].classList.add("purple");
      setTimeout(() => {
        titleArtArray[2].classList.remove("purple");
      }, 500);
    }, 500);
  }, 500);
}, 2000);
  
</script>
<div class="art-column">
  <h1 class="art-text">Think</h1>
  <h1 class="art-text">Design</h1>
  <h1 class="art-text">Code</h1>
</div>
<style>
  .purple {
    color: purple;
  }
</style>
```